# wheezy raspbian install - login prompt at the command line

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, raspbian-wheezy, user

**Problem**

I'm just a Pi noobie and so I have some remedial questions.  I finished imaging my SD card with wheezy.  When I booted up with the SD card, it took me through a setup process and without thinking, I changed what I thought was the login password.

Now on restarting the Pi, I'm being prompted for a login.  But I don't know what the account name is.
I've tried "root" and the new password I specified.  But that doesn't work.
Also tried "admin" and the new password.

Am I right in assuming the default account name is root? 
If I wanted to reset the account, is the only way to format the SD card and redo the imaging process?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was probably the `pi` user; the only two login accounts initially are `pi` and `root`.

pi is user and raspberry is password initially.

UN = pi
PW = raspberry